# A place to ask about specific code to make sure I'm programming correctly

Tags: discussion

I'm taking some C++ classes in school and my instructors are awesomely unhelpful in answering questions as are other resources such as friends who struggle or whatever else.

When I have a specific question such as *"did I code this correctly and efficiently as possible"* I'd like to be able to post that code somewhere and get feedback from people who actually want to help me.

Every time I ask something here I get down voted, probably because my questions are too specific, so I ask this in a general form to better anyone else who also struggles and needs some place for help.

I always thought programmers were supposed to be nice but the ones here give me lots of cold shoulders. I have several friends who get the same treatment, so we don't want to bother anyone else here with our stupidity.

Comment: _"I'd like to be able to post that code somewhere and get feedback from people who actually want to help me."_ That sounds like you want to ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: _"did I code this correctly and efficiently as possible"_ For the first point compile your code and debug it before asking here, for the 2nd point ask at SE Code Review.

Comment: *"I always thought programmers were supposed to be nice"* - I always thought they had a reputation for being anti-social, which led to them spending their times alone with computers instead of learning how to relate to people.  In any case, while there is some level of legitimate rudeness, a lot of what people perceive as rude comes from a desire for efficiency--which is necessary when there are so many questions per day, in order to make it more useful for people Googling for information--who are the "long tail" of who the site is *actually* for, moreso than the questioner's one-time benefit.

Comment: I went through your question history. You don't get downvoted for stupidity, we are here to help and we all started with nothing. The real reason you get downvoted a lot is that your questions are low-effort "do my homework for me" questions, which we frown upon. I promise you, if you post a clear question with all the relevant code and errors included, and there is a definitive answer to it, you will get help here. Like others said, code review is a good place for letting others comment on your code.

Comment: It's very easy (when communicating via text-only medium) to come off as rude even when you didn't intend to... especially if you've forgotten what it's like to be a clueless newbie, and/or are feeling a bit irked at the questioner for not forming his/her question very well, or for not grasping an issue that seems (to you, because of your greater experience) self-evident.

Comment: My first few posts were a learning experience...I even called Stack Overflow folks "sharks" in my comments! If you keep asking and participating you will get the hang of it as you start to learn the culture and dos and don'ts. Don't give up though if you intend to be a programmer! SO and her sister sites have been the most useful new tool to me as a professional programmer.

Comment: "I get down voted probably because my questions are too specific" Hmm, my impression is this is not the true reason. It's important to distill the problem/question and present it as clearly as possible to make a good, useful, answerable question. Also (re)searching before is important. But then, if the question is clear, there is no limit to how specific it can be. At least I do not know of any close reason that says so.

Comment: Credit where credit is due, at least you're asking how you can do better.  That's where we all start.

Comment: Dude... if you're still a student, and take downvoting low-quality questions personal, trust me - you're *not* ready for a codereview in which someone may not try his best to not hurt your feelings by telling you your code is crap in ways X,Y and Z.
@JoeGayetty hey, no need to be rude there man ;)

Answer (score 54):

If your code works correctly (to the best of your knowledge), then post it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).  That is the Stack Exchange site to get suggestions on how to improve your working code.

That said, none of the last three questions you have posted on Stack Overflow were actually "did I code this correctly and efficiently as possible" questions.  They would not have been allowable on Code Review because they don't contain working code.  My guess is that they were downvoted on Stack Overflow because you seem to be asking for a tutorial.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015024/how-do-i-store-an-array-backwards-and-manipulate-it

  This one has placeholder comments; you are basically asking for code to be written for you.
- [Deleting a number from an array that is being pointed to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708895/deleting-a-number-from-an-array-that-is-being-pointed-to)

  The code does't work.  The question would be better if you had posted a runnable example, the expected result, the wrong output, and your thoughts about what you think might have gone wrong.  As it is, your `main` won't compile, and it looks like a low-effort question because you didn't include those four things.
- [How do I pass a complex array of structures to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452794/how-do-i-pass-a-complex-array-of-structures-to-a-function)

  "I have no idea where to go from here" isn't a good question; it's asking for a tutorial.

It's not a matter of people on Stack Overflow being nice or not.  It's just hard to help you in a question-and-answer format.  Ideally, your questions should be formulated according to the [MCVE](/help/mcve) guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

First, ask google.

Second, you can try to post a very specific question here with precise objectives (the more efficient way to ..., memory optimized way to ..., minimum operations to ...) if it does not exist yet (otherwise make your objectives clear in the title if the question is similar).

Third, there are good LinkedIn groups with answers for all-level questions.

Last options, you may ask quora community. It's less formal and more day to day questions I think ...

Edit:

[πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) answer about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ seems like a good idea for clean code review.
But if you want general answers, go to LinkedIn or Quora.

Comment: @Feathercrown Maybe the voters disagree with "make your objectives clear in the title if the question is similar". That sounds a bit strange. Or maybe because of some other disagreement. I upvoted because of mentioning Quora. I always perceived StackOverflow to be the service with a higher quality limit and Quora to be the place for more open-ended, imprecise, chatty questions. While this is no judgement about what is better or worse, it's useful to mention the alternatives.